# JQuery for wordpress any post type sub-menu ALL Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Attached is image of what I want to do with JQuery css, not by css alone. The red color is changed in sub-menu.

[image]

I have a JQuery that modifies the link and title for any post type in Wordpress. Now, I am trying to write additional JQuery that modifies the hidden sub-menu that is displayed during hover. How do you modify a sub-menu if its not visible yet until hover? In particular the link that displays to go to list of all post types commonly in Wordpress, the link that is named **All Posts** or **All Pages**, etc. That is the sub-menu I am referring to.

Comment: It would _really_ be helpful to create a fiddle example here on stack overflow to show the behavior. Use the `<>` icon on the editor toolbar to help. Jquery options are available on the left-side menu, I believe 3.3.1 is the highest that can be selected.

Comment: Wordpress was not mentioned in the question, so if this is what is used, then add a tag for that too to increase visibility to those users. (also add to the question which wordpress version that you have) ... but yes, a fiddle would be helpful, because surely someone here that might be using wordpress can validate if there may be an issue, or if the issue is more general, even to those not using wordpress (such as me) may see the same issue without wordpress, or may spot trouble in the code. Keep the fiddle _as short as possible_ that reproduces the issue, we do **not** need 10k lines of code.

Comment: I updated this question to try and get my account reactivated here. Anyone please write a answer if you know the answer...